# Get return and assign value from promise

Tags: reactjs, promise

I am trying to return value from fetch and assign it to a variable. data is returning but when I am trying to assign value in a variable that time I am getting this output.

here are my code and output

```
var getval=helper.GetRecord(objParam).then(response=>{return response});
```

**Output**
Promise {}
**proto**: Promise
[[PromiseStatus]]: "fulfilled"
[[PromiseValue]]: Object
**Record: "2020-08-15 02:18:55"**
**proto**: Object

how to get this record data in variable

Comment: You cannot synchronously get the result value of a promise. You will need to wait for it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to resolve the final promise. Per the [MDN docs: Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

```
fetch('http://example.com/movies.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

In your case

```
helper.GetRecord(objParam)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => /*use data*/);
```

or assign it to a variable using `await`

```
const response = await helper.GetRecord(objParam);
const getval = await response.json();
```

If `GetRecord()` returns a resolved object instead of the complete response from `fetch()` you still can't assign it to `getval` in the way you are attempting as `.then()` always returns a promise. In this case you need to simply handle the response in the callback.

```
helper.GetRecord(objParam)
  .then(response => /*use response*/);
```

or assign it to a variable using `await`

```
const getval = await helper.GetRecord(objParam);
```